# How to execute dotnet .dll from outside working directory

Tags: .net, dll, command-line-interface

I am trying to execute a dotnet .dll from outside it's build directory (working directory).

When I do that the appsettings.json file is ignored.

**Is there a way to set the working directory? Or can I specify where the appsettings.json file is located?**

something like that:

```
# option A:
$env:DOTNET_WORKING_DIRECOTRY = "C:\root\build"
dotnet c:\root\build\hello.dll

# option B:
dotnet c:\root\build\hello.dll --appsettings c:\root\build\appsettings.json
```

## Details

```
C:\root
└───build
    ├───appsettings.json
    └───hello.dll
```

works:

```
cd C:\root\build
dotnet hello.dll
```

does not work (ignores appsettings.json):

```
cd C:\root
dotnet build/hello.dll
```